# Is access token saved in Cache.db-wal bad for iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, token, caching, keychain

tested iOS application probably uses special Token directive for authentication to server. This token was found in file Cache.db-wal. I can't understand, why it's just in this one file and not in Cache.db as well. Moreover, I'm not sure whether it's ok to keep this token (useable till timeout or next logon) in this file instead of e.g. keychain. Can anybody give some points whether this solution is secure enough?